# How to restrict code checkout only to a certain user/machine combination

Tags: git, github, ssh, code-access-security

How to restrict git code checkout only to a certain user/machine combination. Our projects reside in github and the user uses SSH to communicate with github for code access.

If the private key is copied to a different machine (say in his home), its possible to download the source code on a different machine.

We are within a LAN environment and I would prefer to restrict code access strictly to the single machine which is used by developer.

How should I enforce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I enforce this?

Not from GitHub itself.

Only a private git repo hosting server can, with the addition of an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/), offer [restriction from IP address](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook.html#example-2-restricting-by-source-ip-address)

```
repo foo
    RW+ VREF/FROM/192.168.48.0/23   =   @junior-devs
    -   VREF/FROM                   =   @junior-devs
```

Here, any user registered in the group "`junior-devs`" would have access at all to repo `foo`, unless they access it from `192.168.48.0`.